# Advice on rejecting job offer from recommender

Tags: graduate-admissions, recommendation-letter, job

I worked for this professor last summer for free and am going to ask her to be recommender for PhD application. This year I asked to work with her again, however this time I need salary. So she offered me a job, however there is no salary. Furthermore, there is no other professor involved in this project so I cannot get another recommender as well. I am not really interested in this. What can I do so that I do not piss her off and she still writes me a letter of recommendation?
Thank you all

Comment: You can politely reject the offer and ask for her letter. What else do you think you could do?

Comment: So how can I reject that? Just say Im not interested?

Comment: You can explain (in one or two sentences) that you enjoyed working with her last year, but that you are currently looking for paid offers and a PhD position, and that it would be helpful if she could write you a letter of recommendation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say that you really wish you could accept her offer but, unfortunately, lack of money is becoming an issue for you. You need to start earning money (in order to live). With regret you will have to find a funded position even if it is not so desirable.